# Calculation Errors when Using javax.swing.JOptionPane for Input

Tags: java, swing, math

So I've started working the basics of creating a GUI in Java. I've started by creating a basic math program that will solve a Quadratic where the inputs are directed through an Option Pane. However, I noticed that the program is giving me solutions with i whenever there is no imaginary solution.
Here is the code:

```
package window.math;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WindowMath {

public static void Solve(double a, double b, double c){ //Gives the input of A, B, C to the formula
    double x;
    x = Math.pow(b,2) - 4 * a * c; //Determines whether solution will have imaginary numbers or not
    if (x >= 0){ //Real Solution output
        double y;
        double z;
        double j;
        double k;
        double l;
        y = -b + Math.sqrt(x);
        z = -b - Math.sqrt(x);
        j= 2 * a;
        k = y / j;
        l = z / j;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The solutions are x = " + k + " and x = " + l + ".", "Quadratic Solver", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } else { //Imaginary Solution Output
        double j;
        double v;
        double w;
        double y;
        double z;
        y = Math.abs(x);
        w = Math.sqrt(y);
        j = 2 * a;
        v = w / j;
        z = -b / j;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The solutions are x = " + z + " + " + v + "i and x = " + z + " - " + v + "i.", "Quadratic Solver", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a:");
    String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter b:");
    String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter c:");
    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(a);
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(b);
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble(b);
    Solve(num1,num2,num3);
}
```

}

When I run three numbers that give the solution with an imaginary number, then the program works fine. However, for something like a = 1, b = 2, and c = 1, the solution should be x = -1, x = -1. Only real solutions. Instead, the output gives me "x = -1.0 + 1.0i, x = -1.0 - 1.0i. I'm currently coding in NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) and using Java update 1.8.0_144 and JavaVM 25.144-b01. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @BrenoQ I can't believe I completely overlooked that. Thank you so much. Hopefully I don't make this error again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is in the following line (from your `main` method):

```
double num3 = Double.parseDouble (b);
```

It should be:

```
double num3 = Double.parseDouble (c);
```

Comment: faster answering than me, but i totally agree :)